# Force django-admin startproject if project folder already exists

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to start new django project in already existing folder and obviously get

```
CommandError: '/home/user/projectfolder' already exists.
```

Is there some way to force startproject command to create project in an existing folder? I have some important data in that folder and also git folder so I don't want to move it somewhere and then move it back.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Just use the current directory:

```
cd /home/user/projectfolder

django-admin.py startproject project .
```

The use of `.` just instructs Django to create a project in the current directory while:

`django-admin.py startproject`

instructs Django to create a project and create the necessary directory

> If only the project name is given, both the project directory and
> project package will be named  and the project directory
> will be created in the current working directory.

This fails because of the existing directory **which is not a bug** but a constrain in order to prevent accidents.

Comment: lol I thought 'project' is my project's name, while you literally mean 'project'

Answer (score 15):

You can make too like this:

```
 django-admin startproject name_project path_project
```

Example:

```
 django-admin startproject example /tmp/example
```